# How to store the results of random numbers

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make a dice roller that can roll multiple die and store the results in an array

Here is the code I am using:

```
const d4 = Math.floor((Math.random() * 4) + 1)
let dieAmount = 10
let arrayOfResults = []

for (let i = 1; i <= dieAmount; i++) {
    arrayOfResults.push(d4)
}
console.log(arrayOfResults)
```

From my understanding of the for loop arrayOfResults.push(d4) should run 10 times then put each result in a new index but the array that is returned contains 10 indexes of the same value. What is going on here?

Comment: the fact that `d4` is a `const` should be a clue ... not saying changing it to `let` or `var` would make any difference, but since a `const` can't have a new value assigned to it, it's clear that it has a *const*ant value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason of your answer is `Math.random` have already executed and the `const d4` already has a value, so inside the loop you are just pushing same value multiple times but you need a new random number on each iteration, so call the `Math.random` function inside the loop

```js
let dieAmount = 10
let arrayOfResults = []

for (let i = 1; i <= dieAmount; i++) {
  const d4 = Math.floor((Math.random() * 4) + 1)
  arrayOfResults.push(d4)
}
console.log(arrayOfResults)
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but you should call random number in every loop, then only you'll get different random number in every loop like as below:

```
let dieAmount = 10;
let arrayOfResults = [];

for (let i = 1; i <= dieAmount; i++) {
    const d4 = Math.floor((Math.random() * 4) + 1);
    arrayOfResults.push(d4);
}
console.log(arrayOfResults);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `d4` is `const` and you adding it to the array each time.

You could consider using `Array::from()`.
A nice shorthand for `Math.random()` could be `|` operator.

```js
const arrayOfResults = Array.from({length:10}, () => 1 + Math.random() * 4 | 0);

console.log(arrayOfResults)
```